# What does "USING table1, table1 as vtable" mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, syntax

I'm new to MySQL and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what this means:

```
DELETE from keywords USING keywords, keywords as vtable 
WHERE (keywords.id > vtable.id) && (keywords.keyword=vtable.keyword)
```

Specifically, what does this part `USING keywords, keywords as vtable` mean?

Is there a better way to write this query that would be equivalent? I've read that creating virtual tables isn't efficient.

Also, is the `.` separating the table and the column?

Comment: I would say that the query removes duplicate keywords

Answer (score 3):

`vtable` is an alias for the keywords table so that it can be self-joined.  No different from any alias, but selection of the specific alias `vtable` may have led you to believe that there is some special virtual table mechanism involved.  There isn't.

From an efficiency standpoint, this looks like a normal use of a self-join.  It should be reasonably efficient, if there are indexes on the id and perhaps keywords field.

Also the dot `.`, does indeed separate table and column name (or table alias and column name).

Here's the same query with a different alias name:

`DELETE from keywords

USING keywords, keywords as k2

WHERE (keywords.id > k2.id) && (keywords.keyword=k2.keyword)`

And here's the whole query done a little differently, but maybe less confusingly, with a JOIN:

`DELETE keywords

FROM keywords

INNER JOIN keywords as k2 ON keywords.keyword = k2.keyword

WHERE keywords.id > k2.id`

Comment: +1 for the explanation.  How about an example showing the same query with explicit join syntax (ON rather than WHERE)?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Can you comment on what `USING keywords, keywords as vtable` does? Is it constructing a `vtable` with two copies of `keywords`? Or does the `USING` apply to the `DELETE FROM keywords` statement?

Comment: When used with a DELETE the USING keyword does the following:  It names tables to use for selection--but the delete only happens on the table named with the `FROM` **before** the using.  See the 3rd syntax given here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html.

Comment: Also, be aware that USING produces a join.  Since no join condition is specified this is a cartesian join.  However, the WHERE conditions are actually used like a join conditions in your example query.  Normally USING is used with a specified column (same column name in both tables) to specify what column to join on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very fabulous method of query as whenever you got stuck in a condition such that you want to manipulate in a table by comparing itself from a record of same table.

The USING keyword can use a list of columns that appear in both tables and is equivalent to saying C.ID = O.ID AND S.ID = O.ID.

```
            mysql>
            mysql> CREATE TABLE Employee(
                ->     id            int,
                ->     first_name    VARCHAR(15),
                ->     last_name     VARCHAR(15),
                ->     start_date    DATE,
                ->     end_date      DATE,
                ->     salary        FLOAT(8,2),
                ->     city          VARCHAR(10),
                ->     description   VARCHAR(15)
                -> );
            Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> create table job (
                ->   id         int,
                ->   title      VARCHAR(20)
                -> );
            Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into Employee(id,first_name, last_name, start_date, end_Date,   salary,  City,       Description)
                ->              values (1,'Jason',    'Martin',  '19960725',  '20060725', 1234.56, 'Toronto',  'Programmer');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into Employee(id,first_name, last_name, start_date, end_Date,   salary,  City,       Description)
                ->               values(2,'Alison',   'Mathews',  '19760321', '19860221', 6661.78, 'Vancouver','Tester');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into Employee(id,first_name, last_name, start_date, end_Date,   salary,  City,       Description)
                ->               values(3,'James',    'Smith',    '19781212', '19900315', 6544.78, 'Vancouver','Tester');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into Employee(id,first_name, last_name, start_date, end_Date,   salary,  City,       Description)
                ->               values(4,'Celia',    'Rice',     '19821024', '19990421', 2344.78, 'Vancouver','Manager');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into Employee(id,first_name, last_name, start_date, end_Date,   salary,  City,       Description)
                ->               values(5,'Robert',   'Black',    '19840115', '19980808', 2334.78, 'Vancouver','Tester');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into Employee(id,first_name, last_name, start_date, end_Date,   salary,  City,       Description)
                ->               values(6,'Linda',    'Green',    '19870730', '19960104', 4322.78,'New York',  'Tester');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into Employee(id,first_name, last_name, start_date, end_Date,   salary,  City,       Description)
                ->               values(7,'David',    'Larry',    '19901231', '19980212', 7897.78,'New York',  'Manager');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into Employee(id,first_name, last_name, start_date, end_Date,   salary,  City,       Description)
                ->               values(8,'James',    'Cat',     '19960917',  '20020415', 1232.78,'Vancouver', 'Tester');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (1,'Tester');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (2,'Accountant');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (3,'Developer');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (4,'Coder');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (5,'Director');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (6,'Mediator');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (7,'Proffessor');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (8,'Programmer');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

            mysql> insert into job (id, title) values (9,'Developer');
            Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql> select * from job;
            +------+------------+
            | id   | title      |
            +------+------------+
            |    1 | Tester     |
            |    2 | Accountant |
            |    3 | Developer  |
            |    4 | Coder      |
            |    5 | Director   |
            |    6 | Mediator   |
            |    7 | Proffessor |
            |    8 | Programmer |
            |    9 | Developer  |
            +------+------------+
            9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

            mysql> select * from Employee;
            +------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+
            | id   | first_name | last_name | start_date | end_date   | salary  | city      | description |
            +------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+
            |    1 | Jason      | Martin    | 1996-07-25 | 2006-07-25 | 1234.56 | Toronto   | Programmer  |
            |    2 | Alison     | Mathews   | 1976-03-21 | 1986-02-21 | 6661.78 | Vancouver | Tester      |
            |    3 | James      | Smith     | 1978-12-12 | 1990-03-15 | 6544.78 | Vancouver | Tester      |
            |    4 | Celia      | Rice      | 1982-10-24 | 1999-04-21 | 2344.78 | Vancouver | Manager     |
            |    5 | Robert     | Black     | 1984-01-15 | 1998-08-08 | 2334.78 | Vancouver | Tester      |
            |    6 | Linda      | Green     | 1987-07-30 | 1996-01-04 | 4322.78 | New York  | Tester      |
            |    7 | David      | Larry     | 1990-12-31 | 1998-02-12 | 7897.78 | New York  | Manager     |
            |    8 | James      | Cat       | 1996-09-17 | 2002-04-15 | 1232.78 | Vancouver | Tester      |
            +------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+---------+-----------+-------------+
            8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql>
            mysql>
            The syntax looks like the following:
            mysql>
            mysql> SELECT C.First_Name, C.Last_Name, O.title
                -> FROM Employee AS C
                -> LEFT JOIN job as O USING (ID);
            +------------+-----------+------------+
            | First_Name | Last_Name | title      |
            +------------+-----------+------------+
            | Jason      | Martin    | Tester     |
            | Alison     | Mathews   | Accountant |
            | James      | Smith     | Developer  |
            | Celia      | Rice      | Coder      |
            | Robert     | Black     | Director   |
            | Linda      | Green     | Mediator   |
            | David      | Larry     | Proffessor |
            | James      | Cat       | Programmer |
            +------------+-----------+------------+
            8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql>
            mysql>
            mysql> drop table job;
            Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

            mysql> drop table Employee;
            Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

            mysql>
            mysql>
            In this example, the USING keyword would be like using the ON keyword with C.ID = O.ID following it.
            This is another shortcut to save time.
            mysql>
```